# List files and directories that a user has permission to

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

How can one list the content of a directory but only show directories and files that a user has Read access to?

I have worked out this but it only lists files owned:

```
find /dir/to/search -user johnsmith1 -ls
```

I was thinking a possible alternative was to "sudo su johnsmith1" and then ls or find but I am not sure if that is possible either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List directories & files that a user (`ubuntu` in the examples) **has read permissions** to:

```
find -exec sudo -u ubuntu test -r '{}' \; -print
```

List directories & files that a user **has write permissions** to:

```
find -exec sudo -u ubuntu test -w '{}' \; -print
```

List directories & files that a user **has execute permissions** to:

```
find -exec sudo -u ubuntu test -x '{}' \; -print
```

List directories & files that a user **has read, write & execute permissions** to:

```
find -exec sudo -u ubuntu test -rwx '{}' \; -print
```

Comment: This is definitely the easiest and safest so far!  The others did not factor in secondary groups.

Comment: To do this for the user being used, just omit the `sudo` part with the user, like this:  `find -exec test -x '{}' \; -print`

Answer (score 3):

I found a way!

```
find -maxdepth 1 \( -type d -or -type f \) \( \( -user johnsmith1 -perm /u=r \) -o \( -group johnsmith1 -perm /g=r \) -o -perm /o=r \) -ls
```

Comment: This will miss the case where a file is readable as a result of the user's *secondary* group memberships, I think?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by piping the output of ls into grep
so if you only wanted to review directories or files which you have read permission only you could use this command

```
ls -l | grep [d,-]r--
```

if you wanted to review directories or files which you have read, write, and execution permissions you could use this command

```
ls -l | grep [d,-]rwx
```

if you wanted to review directories or files which you have read, and maybe other permissions you could use this command

```
ls -l | grep [d,-]r*
```

Comment: I don't think parsing `ls` output is a good approach - at the least you would need to anchor the matches to the start of the pattern. Your last expression in particular appears to confuse shell globs and regex - it will match the strings `-r`, `,r` and `dr` (you probably meant `[d-]` not `[d,-]`) anywhere - including the user, group and filename. Also get into the habit of quoting patterns when they contain shell special characters such as `*` - otherwise you will get unexpected results when they happen to match filenames.

Comment: No that is precisely the match I wanted, dr* is for directories with read permision. -r * is for files with read permision. The brackets ensure that only strings starting with "-r" and "dr" will be matched. This will only provide secondary matches with filenames if those files include the required permissions because I'm piping from ls -l despite your unsubstantiated opinion about the approach.  if you can demonstrate your claim ill be very surprised.

Comment: `touch drat && chmod -r drat && ls -l | grep [d,-]r*`

Comment: 'touch drat && chmod -r drat && echo 'grasping-at-straws' >> drat && ls -l | grep [d,-]r* '
'more drat'
> more: cannot open drat: Permission denied

Comment: your demonstration fails to meet the necessary criteria

Comment: I think you meant
`
touch drat && chmod +r drat && echo 'grasping-at-straws' >> drat && ls -l | grep [d,-]r* 
`
which is not a demonstration of your claim either

Comment: keep trying @steeldriver